# PHP mail() with large attachment not sent

Tags: sendmail, email-forwarding

I'm implementing an email forwarder PHP program. Here is my requirement:

- Read the inbox of the particular email account with regular interval
- Incoming mails may have attachment or may not have attachment.
- Attachment may have large size.
- Forward the incoming mails to a destination with the attachment as they are in the original mail, but some mail body texts wil be removed.

I almost succeed. Mails with small file attachments were forwarded to the destination, but the problem is with the large file attachments (zip file about 23MB I tried).
It seems to me mail sending was successful because I did not see any error generated from the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, but I did not receive it in my destination.

What's wrong with the mail() function ? Or should I use [imap_mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail.php) in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using php on commandline, I suppose, the only php limit I can thin of, is the [memory-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).
But most likely this is not a php problem, but you run into the limits of your [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent).
Squirrelmail has some information about [MTA limits](http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/AttachmentSize) (section "Sending the mail with the attachment").

Comment: I have encountered the memory_limit problem before, but I overcome it by increasing memory limit, otherwise I will get Fetal error: Allowed memory limit exhausted..... I think this will be because of the mail() function.

Comment: I assume you are using linux. What is your MTA? or if you don't know: Which linux distribution or os are you using?